# how do you alter items in a list in python?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have this code and I want to know how to append the list so I can sort it by number, high to low

```
data=['red' '1', 'blue' '8', 'green' '2', 'orange' '6']
```

I would like to know how to sort the list by the number from high to low by changing the items in the list so the number is before the colour so it can simply be sorted from high to low.

Here is how the list should be:

```
data=['1' 'red', '8' 'blue', '2' 'green' ,'6' 'orange']
```

Comment: So you have a list of 4 elements? Adjacent string literals are concatenated... are you sure you don't have a list of tuples, or a list of 8 items instead of 4?

Comment: by using `'1' 'red'` python will concatenate the strings, is this what you want? data currently looks like this: `['red1', 'blue8', 'green2', 'orange6']`

Comment: where is the high to low sort?

Comment: List of the 4 items so '1' 'red' is one item...

Comment: Your input format looks wrong according to what you wish to achieve. Use list of tuples instead. Ex: `data=[("red", "1"), ("blue", "8"), ...]`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I want to change the items so it's '1' 'red' then I will just use data.sort()

Comment: @Andrey you can sort it without re-organising the data - you just want it in a better format first... have you tried doing a `print(data)` is that actually the format you really expect?

Comment: @Andrey,  what does you data look like, also sorting by string digits would not work

Comment: @FallenAngel okay, but is there anything I can do to change the content by placing the number before?

Comment: @Andrey so you **do** have a list of tuples then!?

Comment: Check my answer or @mkrieger1's answer

Comment: @JonClements I have a >data.sort() and a print statement, is there any way I can sort the list so it will only take note of the number and print it from high to low, that's basically what I want to achieve

Comment: @Andrey, add exactly what `print data` outputs to your question

Answer (score 2):

If you actually have 8 separate items and want to sort by numbers from high to low you can group them using iter, reversing the order:

```
data=['red', '1', 'blue', '8', 'green' ,'2', 'orange','6']

from itertools import chain
it = iter(data)
grouped = zip(it, it)

data = sorted(((b, a) for a,b in grouped),
          key=lambda x: int(x[0]),reverse=True))

print(list(chain(*data)))
['8', 'blue', '2', 'green', '1', 'red']
```

But you my be better off keeping the elements in tuples:

```
print(data)

[('8', 'blue'), ('2', 'green'), ('1', 'red')]
```

If your data is actually as posted  use itertools to create pairings, ad actually sorting correctly casting the digits to int:

```
from itertools import dropwhile as dw, takewhile as tw
data=['red' '1', 'blue' '8', 'green' '2', 'orange' '6']
data = sorted((("".join(dw(str.isalpha,s)), "".join(tw(str.isalpha,s)))
               for s in data),key=lambda x: int(x[0]),reverse=True)
print(data)
[('8', 'blue'), ('6', 'orange'), ('2', 'green'), ('1', 'red')]
```

Or rejoin as strings:

```
print(["".join(tup) for tup in data])
['8blue', '2green', '1red']
```

Comment: Isn't `dict(zip(it, it)).items()` just the same as `zip(it, it)`?

Comment: @mkrieger1, yes, I was originally going to do something different. Anyway  the answer would still work, we don't always get to *choose a proper data structure* when sometimes it comes from another source so manually changing the data is not really a soultion

Comment: I do not deny that your solution works.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should choose a proper data structure representing the pairs of numbers and colors, for example a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences). You make tuples by separating items with commas and enclosing them in parentheses:

```
data = [('red', 1), ('blue', 8), ('green', 2), ('orange', 6)]
```

(Note that I also removed the quotes around the numbers, so that they are really numbers, and not strings.)

To swap colors and numbers:

```
>>> [(number, color) for color, number in data]
[(1, 'red'), (8, 'blue'), (2, 'green'), (6, 'orange')]
```

To sort by the number, from low to high:

```
>>> sorted((number, color) for color, number in data)
[(1, 'red'), (2, 'green'), (6, 'orange'), (8, 'blue')]
```

To sort by the number, from high to low:

```
>>> sorted(((number, color) for color, number in data), reverse=True)
[(8, 'blue'), (6, 'orange'), (2, 'green'), (1, 'red')]
```

Comment: The quotes would be there for a reason i.e they are strings

Comment: But the reason may be that OP didn't know better, so I proposed a better alternative to start with.